# DTS for SQL Server 2005 Express Edition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, dts

What did Microsoft rename DTS to for SQL Server 2005 Express Edition?

Where is the download link to the SQL Server 2005 Express Edition DTS utility?

---

i've been searching for half an hour, and i can't find a definitive answer.

i need to import data from a data source into an SQL Server 2005 Express Edition database.

Answer (score 3):

DTS is renamed SSIS and SSIS is not part of Express editions.

Comment: So, to confirm, you cannot import data into SQL Server 2005 Express Edition?

Comment: With SQL Express you don't have the SSIS runtime and editors. But you can develop SSIS packages on a payed edition and have them import/export data from/to an Express edition though.

Comment: 'Import' is a pretty broad term.  In addition to SSIS, there's also BULK INSERT if you're familiar with that.

Comment: @Remus: Is SSIS really DTS renamed? I have always understood SSIS to be a completely new SQL Server Technology, rather than say an upgrade to an existing one (DTS)?

Comment: I mean 'rename' as in the 'the feature formerly known as DTS is now known as SSIS'. It is a complete rewrite indeed, since the technology had to change from native and COM to managed and CLR. In that sense is not an 'upgrade'. But as scope, usage scenarios and functionality it clearly extends on the DTS concepts.

Answer (score 0):

DTS is not longer available in it's pure form in SQL Server 2005 and above.

A new technology platform called [SQL Server Integration Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx) (SSIS) was developed and has replaced the functionality previously on offer via Data Transformation Services (DTS).

For instructions on how to "migrate" DTS packages to SSIS refer to the following Microsoft Books Online Reference: [Migrating Data Transformation Services Packages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143501(SQL.90).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you install [Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Backward Compatibility Components](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24793) you will have get the DTS stuff even on SQL Server 2005 Express. It will then be in c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Binn or similar. DTSWizard.exe is probably what you are looking for.